# jQuery, hover active only when the fade in on page load ends

Tags: jquery, load, hover, fadein

I'm pretty a beginner with jQuery!

I need to have some divs to fadeIn on page loads, and i can do it.
I need to have them showing with different delay and times, and i can do it.
Every div has an image that fadeIn when you hover the relative div, and i can do it.

The problem is that the animation of the image on hover, start still if the fadeIn of the div is not ended.

I want that if the user hover the div that is still going with fadeIn nothing happens.
If you hover a div that is totally show then the image starts the fadeIn.

Here is my HTML

```
<div id="immagine1">
<img src="images/logo_key_css.png" alt="logo_key_css" width="169" height="53"/>
</div>
<div id="immagine2">
<img src="images/logo_key_css.png" alt="logo_key_css" width="169" height="53"/>
</div>
```

Here is my jQuery

```
$(window).load(function () {

$('#immagine1').hide();
$('#immagine1').stop().fadeIn(1000);
$('#immagine2').hide();
$('#immagine2').stop().delay(2500).fadeIn(2500);
$('div').hover(
        function(){ $(this).find('img').fadeIn(1000);
    });

     });
```

And the img css

```
img{
display:none;
}
```

How can i "disable" the hover effect till the end of the fadeIn on page load?

Thanks!

[This is the test page](http://www.marcodeliso.it/jquery/test.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this will do what you are looking for.  Basically, what you need to do is wait until the `<div>` has faded in completely before you bind the hover event for the image.  You can achieve this by doing the event binding in the [callback](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp) for the `<div>` fadeIn.  Additionally, since you are only doing something on the hoverIn event (and not on hoverOut), you can use .mouseenter() instead of .hover()

Here is the code:

```
$(function() {
    $('div img').hide();
    $('#immagine1').hide().fadeIn(5000, function() {
        $('div').mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).find('img').fadeIn('1000');
        });
    });
});
```

And here's a working demo of it: http://jsfiddle.net/vYz3t/

Answer (score 0):

Look, i doesn't understand your real problem, but try this:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('#immagine1, #immagine2').hide();
    $('#immagine1').hover(
            function(){
                $(this).fadeIn(1000);
            },
            function(){
                $(this).fadeOut(1000);
            }
    );
    $('#immagine2').hover(
            function(){
                $(this).fadeIn(1000);
            },
            function(){
                $(this).fadeOut(1000);
            }
   );
});
```

Or take a look on [jQuery hover docs](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: thanks for your reply but your code seems to not work at all. 
I've set online a test page so you can see what i need.

If you reload the page staying with the mouse away from the box and then you go hover the box, you'll see appear a "brown" box.
If you reload the page staying with the mouse on the box position, you'll see that the "brown" box start showing before the div (black or white) ends its fade In.

I want that the user can start the hover effect only when the div finish is fadeIn. Hope now is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but maybe you can get your desired effect by using [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) to explicitly place the hover animation at the end of the queue:

```
$('div').hover(function() {
  $(this).queue(function() {
    $(this).find('img').fadeIn(1000);
  });
});​
```

The fade-in effect will begin after pending animations in the default queue ("fx") are complete. Here's [a fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/HtGkV/) demonstrating the concept; perhaps it will point you in the right direction.

Comment: I think that you have understand what i need to achive.
Your code isn't working either, it seems with a syntax error but i can't figure out why.

Here is a test page link of the test http://tinyurl.com/32thnx7

Comment: Your tinyurl link points to a page that has your original code -- not the queue() approach.

Comment: i know, i can't make it work with your code. thanks anyway :)